# EXPO EAS BUILD "HTTP Error: Response code 400 (Bad Request)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to build an apk to test my app but every time I run eas build i get the same error. I've already searched everywhere and can't find a solution.

[image: Image of the error]

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Running:

```
expo update
```

solved this problem for me and I was able to successfully run eas build again.  I believe there were incompatible packages installed that needed to be updated.

Comment: I've did it a bunch of times and unfortunately it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it looks like my ISP was blocking the requisition, using VPN solved the problem